# Asana and requirements management

Tags: requirements, tools, asana

I am looking for a way to include requirements management in Asana.

Right now we have a very powerful integration with Instagantt, where projects and their scheduled tasks are in sync with Asana's project columns.

What I would like is to also be able to handle requirements for all parts of the project in a similar fashion.

For example, say Project is made of three phases: Alpha, Beta, and Release. In Asana's Project page, I create three columns, one per phase. Are there ways to organize requirements through the three phases so that I can associate requirements 1,2,3 with Alpha; 4,5,6 with Beta; and 7 with Release? Obviously, in a way that can later be changed, say deciding that req. 3 will not be met with Alpha, but rather with Beta.

The only way that comes to my mind at the moment is to use Instagantt milestones, but it would be unclear to visualize them, and complicated to maintain. Not to mention that actual milestones will be hard to distinguish.

Comment: This has a VTC flag but it is not seeking a software recommendation.  I would recommend my fellow PMSE'rs take greater care when flagging users questions; especially new users.